# remote desktop - How can I enable RemoteApp serving in Windows 10?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-10, remoteapp

It can be enabled in Windows 7/8/8.1 by some tools.

When I use [RemoteApp tool](http://www.kimknight.net/remoteapptool) in Windows 10 PRO, and create rdp file with a valid configuration, the client can't run rdp file. Login window appears but when I login, nothing is happening (I am logging in with my laptop in same network, its Windows 10 PRO too, remote desktop woks fine).

I can see succesfull login in server's event viewer. So it's not a network issue, its not an account issue. I think something is different in Windows 10 about RemoteApp.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and used the exact same tool.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No, sorry. Spent a lot of time but no success @jj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it's **not** supported on the **Professional** version of Windows.  You would need to run the Enterprise or Education version of Windows 10 in order for it to work.  I ran into the exact same problem, where it'd worked fine on my system running Windows 7 Ultimate, but would just disappear when running on Windows 10 Pro.

According to the developer's website (http://www.kimknight.net)

> RemoteApp Tool requires:
>
> - Microsoft .Net Framework 4
> - Windows 7 Enterprise or Ultimate   -or-
> - Windows 8 Enterprise   -or-
> - Windows 10 Enterprise or Education   -or-
> - Windows XP SP3
> - It also works with Windows Server 2008 and newer.
>
> **Note: If you try to host RemoteApps on any other edition of Windows
>   (eg Win 7/8/10 Professional), the tool will run but RemoteApps will
>   not work. The RDP client will appear to be connecting, then just
>   disappear.**

Comment: Tested it now on (unmodified) Windows 10 Pro 1709 and it works just fine. Created App, copied .rdp to another pc, ran it, loggged in and Paint opened

Comment: @trogper, could you please give exact steps what you've done to make it work? I cannot connect to my Win10 Pro

Comment: @Suncatcher I made a chat room, please go there  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83407/remote-desktop

Comment: joined the room

Answer (score 4):

Work on Windows 10 pro

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services]
"fAllowUnlistedRemotePrograms"=dword:00000001